# Class 'DOMDocument' not found on Centos Laravel

Tags: xml, laravel, centos

I am creating the reset password feature on Laravel framework. It works fine in local but when I built it on CentOS server, it returns "Class 'DOMDocument' not found" message.
I also did some research and already installed php-xml. This is result when I command php -m:

```
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

Could someone gives me a solution. I am using php7.2

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I know I need to restart php-fpm to make it work. So the final necessary command is:

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```